# Books to read to understand Terence Tao's Analytic Number Theory Papers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

I tried to understand Terence Tao's Analytic Number Theory Papers. For example, this paper, Every Odd Number Greater Than 1 is The Sum of at Most Five Primes.

Which books shall I read to prepare myself to understand those papers ? Maybe there will be a sequence of books ?

I do not have analytic number theory background. The only number theory book I read is Hardy and Wright, Introduction to the Theory of Numbers. My background is in Algebra and Complex Analysis. (I also read a few chapters of Apostol, but I felt it is not enough to understand Terence Tao's papers).

Answer (score 6):

Dr. Tao's papers often evidence a good understanding and use of analytic number theory, additive number theory, and the circle method. So if you want to read your way towards understanding the papers, this would be a good trio to go towards.

For analytic number theory, you want to understand some algebra and some complex analysis. With these, you could understand [Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441928057) and then perhaps Montgomery and Vaughan's [Multiplicative Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107405823).

For additive number theory, you want to understand algebra, real analysis, and probability theory. The best book to understand Tao's papers is Tao and Vu's [Additive Combinatorics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521136563). This is pitched really high, and it's extremely likely that one would need to backtrack and fill in gaps while attempting to go through it.

For the circle method itself, I would recommend Vaughan's [The Hardy-Littlewood Method](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521573475). (This is another name for the circle method). Alternately, since every application of the method is so different, you might just try to understand it directly from the papers themselves.

A good supplement to the last two books, and a good book in general, is Nathanson's [Additive Number Theory, the Classical Bases](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038794656X) which approaches some of the classical results of additive number theory, sometimes using the circle method.