# Representation of rational numbers by Bernoulli numbers

Tags: number-theory, bernoulli-numbers, additive-combinatorics

Denote by $B$ the set of all Bernoulli numbers.

Is it true that:

**(a)** For every rational number $r$ there exist a number $k=2^q$ (for some positive integer $q$) and  numbers $a_1,\cdots,a_k\in B$ such that 
$$
r=a_1+\cdots+a_{\frac{k}{2}}-(a_{\frac{k}{2}+1}+\cdots+a_k).
$$
Now, denote by $k(r)$ the least $k$ obtained from (a).

**(b)** The set of all $k(r)$, where $r$ runs over all rational numbers, is unbounded above.

Note. One can check that (a) is true when $r$ is an integer, by induction.

Comment: What makes you conjecture that ? Have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/990962) where the main great name is Terence Tao that has a very clear writing on many subjects, in particular arithmetics (additive number theory, etc.).

Comment: We have a similar property for Fibonacci numbers, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989375/representation-of-integers-by-fibonacci-numbers

Comment: Yes, but there is a big difference: Fibonacci numbers are integers, whereas Bernoulli numbers are ratinals,. Moreover The former are very regular, wereas the latter are very irregular.

Comment: The first step to approach the answer is that: Does $B$ generate rational numbers?

Comment: M.H.Hooshmand Of course, by definition, $B$ *is* a set of rational numbers: $B=\{ -1/2, 1/6, -1/30, 1/42, -1/30, 5/66, -691/2730, 7/6,  -3617/510, 43867/798,-174611/330, \cdots \}.$

Comment: @JeanMarie- Sure, but is it true that $B-B=\mathbb{Q}$ or $B+B-(B+B)=\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Don't the Bernoulli numbers grow much too fast for your equations to hold for all $r$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson But also, since [denominators of nonzero Bernoulli numbers are square-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Von_Staudt–Clausen_theorem), you can't make for example $r=\frac{1}{4}$ in **(a)**.